# node.js game server architecture for load balancing

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am new to node.js and multi-player game servers. I have created a multi-player roulette game server in node.js that has a single lobby and multiple tables. The server handles table creation and game state for each table and stores everything in memory. The logic ensures there are always at least 3 empty tables available, but no more than 3 empty tables. It also handles players joining and leaving each table. The server loops through all tables periodically to handle betting time, generating roulette wheel winning number, storing number history, etc. This works great when running the node.js server on a single instance.

I want to be able to easily scale this horizontally across many servers in order to handle as many concurrent connections as I may need in the future. I know I will have to use a solution like redis in order to store the data (rather than in memory) like tables, history, players and send messages across servers and that part I understand.

How should the node.js multi-player game server be designed to allow for table creation/deletion and processing game states for multiple tables across multiple node.js instances on different servers? Obviously we can't do table/creation and process game states from all servers, but then how to do we balance this work load across servers though? or am I thinking about this all wrong?

I can't seem to wrap my head around the best way to do this. Any advice from someone experienced with this type of game server architecture is much appreciated!

Comment: This is an awfully broad question. The best way to scale usually involves a shared backend, but exactly how you set that up depends very much on your application. You can't know for sure until you've done some load testing and profiling at the scale you expect. Most of the Redis chat examples can be scaled horizontally like this, though.

Comment: Yes the shared backend part I understand. I just can't understand how the processing logic should work. In a normal webserver load balanced scenario, it's easy. Shared backend and multiple front end servers that simply serve the content. But in the roulette game server, the processing logic is load balanced which I am not sure how to handle when using a shared backend.

Comment: The shared layer(s), whether you have some shared APIs or just redis, hold the game state and notify everybody at the next layer, until the notification reaches all interested clients. The structure, regardless of tech or how many layers are involved, is a tree with nodes passing all messages up to the root and some messages down to the leaves.